# How to get product options in Opencart?

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am working on a custom page for a customer. On this page I need to show a certain product (product_id = 66), along with its own options.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT pd.name, p.quantity, p.price, pov.quantity AS value_quantity, povd.name AS 
value_name
FROM res_product p
LEFT JOIN res_product_description pd ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id ) 
LEFT JOIN res_product_option_value pov ON ( p.product_id = pov.product_id ) 
LEFT JOIN res_option_value_description povd ON ( pov.product_option_value_id = povd.option_value_id ) 
WHERE p.product_id =66
```

But this does not work.

When I check the table `product_option` I see option id's like 251, 252 and 253 for a specific product. I would like to get the option name, quantity and the price.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure a product with id 66 exists? How about trying without the where and increasing the limit to 200.

Comment: Yes product 66 exists. Without the `WHERE` it actually returns the values I need, but not limited to product_id 66. Limit was added automatically by phpmyadmin, but product 66 only has 3 options.

Comment: Looks like it should work...

Comment: Why *re-inventing* the wheel and **why not re-using the already implemented stuff**??? Did you check the `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` and the method `getProduct()`??? Why not calling this one? Look into `catalog/controller/product/product.php` how the product details with it's options are retrieved.

Comment: I did not, thank you for the location. I will check that out!